# How do I highlight table row when fetching all information with array?

Tags: php, css, mysql, html-table

I'm fetching all rows in mysql database with `mysql_fetch_array()` then showing them in table.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
  echo "<td>" . $row['name']."</td>";
}
```

In this case, if user updates a record on table with my php form, I want to highlight that table row. (changing background color is enough.) How can I do that? Or can I intervent in while loop for only one record?

Comment: set css style property for `<td style='background:red;'></td>` or  `<tr style='background:red;'></tr>`

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: I know but I'm beginner. Thanks for tutorial also, I'll definitely check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this to compare your data in the form (that part is $_POST['id'] - change that with your code) where the user sent his updates with the current row data (I suppose you have something like an id in the sql row result) and change the style of the row.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
  $style = ($row['id'] == $_POST['id']) ? 'style="background-color: red;"' : '';
  echo "<td $style>" . $row['name']."</td>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have insert at the top of the script then

```
//insert to mysql here
$id = mysql_insert_id($resource);
...
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) { 
  if ($id == $row['id']) {
    echo '<td style="color:red">' . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  } else {
    echo "<td>" . $row['name']."</td>";
  }
}
```